# validate https requests using a Certificate Authority (CA)

Tags: node.js, httprequest, subdomain, certificate-authority

I have deployed multiple microservices containing frontend application and backend service.

The frontend application is accessible via *xyz.com* domain. It calls the backend service API endpoint.

So, what I really want is to check is that if any request that is coming from the frontend application is valid and from authentic source on the basis of its domain and subdomain using Certificate Authority in Node.js.

After doing a little bit of research about how it can be done in node.js, 
I found out that it can be done using nodejs `https` module's `request` method. But the problem with this approach is that nodejs maintains a [list of CA certs](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h), which easily gets out of date and there is a chance that the CA that has verified my domain certificate is not part of that list. Although they provide a way to pass additional CA's but still it is a dependency on the user side that they have to maintain the list. I am currently a little bit lost on how to do it in a proper way.

I need help on how to do this process easily and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to validate a domain in node.js

**https.request**

Nodejs https module's request method validates the domain provided against the [chain](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h) of Certificate Authorities root certificate. A code example is given below:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  hostname: 'github.com/',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  rejectUnauthorized: true
};

var ss;
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

> **rejectUnauthorized**: This means that it will validate the server/domain certificate against the [chain](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h) of CA's root certificate.
>
> The only problem with this approach is that this [chain](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h) should be updated regularly otherwise a new domain that is signed by a certificate authority root certificate which is not part of the chain, marked as an invalid certificate(a common example is a self-signed certificate).

[**ssl-validate module**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-validator)

It can also be used but it requires another module to get the domain information.